# Typescript - How to to create array with multiple types

Tags: typescript

I have one common interface and two interfaces "Person" and "Employee" that extend the first one:

```
    export interface Common {
        id: number,
        name: string
      }

      export interface Person extends Common {
        age: number;
      }

      export interface Employee extends Common {
        role: string;
      }
```

I need to have an array mixed with these interfaces, for example this:

```
listOfPeople: Person[] | Employee[] = [{id: 1, name: 'George', age: 4}, {id: 2, name: 'Micheal', role: 'software developer'}];
```

but in this way I got an error. What's the correct way for obtaining the result that I desire?

Comment: If someone really experienced with typescript comes along, I kinda want to append this to the question: is it worth making an array of multiple types like this? My guess is that it probably depends on the application, but my gut instinct tells me there's going to be a lot of headaches down the road, and that 9 times out of 10, it's just better to make something like a `PersonOrEmployee` type with optional `age?` and `role?` parameters. But again, I'm VERY unsure.

Comment: @MichaelHoobler You've got a point. When you for-loop `Array<Person|Employee>` you cannot `item.age` or `item.role` because `Person` and `Employee` do not have those keys in common. However, if you introduce `PersonOrEmployee` you can check `item.age` and `item.role` and do like this `if (item.age) { (item as Person) } else {.(item as Employee) }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the types and declare them as the type for the `listOfPeople` using the union type.

So this would work I guess

`listOfPeople: (Person|Employee)[]`

Because `listOfPeople` is an array that can contain any of these. You must let TS know that it is an array.

`const listOfPeople: (Person|Employee)[] = [{id: 1, name: 'George', age: 4}, {id: 2, name: 'Micheal', role: 'software developer'}];`

Answer (score 2):

Another (maybe clearer) way of writing this type would be:

```
listOfPeople: Array<Person | Employee>;
```